# How to migrate Python models to new models?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I don't know much about Python, but I just started working at a company that uses Python for its main CMS. They gave me the assignment of moving the company from their old product, to their new product. The old product had a custom ORM built on top of SQLAlchemy. The old product had models such as:

```
user
business
client
```

The new product also has a custom ORM built on top of SQLAlchemy. The new product also has models such as:

```
user
business
client
```

However, the fields in these models are completely different.

They have spent 2 years building the new product, a major upgrade of the old product, and now they want to import all the data from the old product into the new product.

I need to do 2 things:

1. Pull data from old product database and serialize the objects
2. Deserialize the objects and put it in the new product database

Here is my confusion:

When I am in the new system, and I deserialize the objects from the old system, I will have a model that thinks its name is "user" or "business" yet it will have fields that don't match the "user" or "business" models that exist in the new system.

I am thinking that this can be solved with namespacing? How do I mark the old "user" objects as "old system"?

Comment: How is it a Python/SQLAlchemy question ? You have legacy data from a legacy schema that you have to migrate to the new schema, it's totally language independant, and is solved by writing a migration script that reads data from the legacy schema and map them - according to rules that only you can know - to the new schema. Python is obviously a good language for such a task but you could do it in about any language that can connect to your databases (or just parse and output text FWIW but that's easier with direct db connections).

Comment: I could write this in any language but we are using SQLAlchemy. And the old SQLAlchemy model names are the same as the new SQLAlchemy model names, but the models are different and have different fields. So I'm guessing I need to namespace the objects or something? I don't know enough about Python about how to tackle this.

Comment: Once again: it has *nothing* to do with Python nor SQLAlchemy nor "models names". You have to different *SQL* schemas, how you migrate from one to the other is *totally* language-independant and *totally* dependant on your schemas and business rules. It' *your* job to provide the mapping (and it might be much more than a simple one-to-one mapping) between the two schemas.

Comment: Bruno, I am unable to understand you. The company that I work at is using Python and SQLAlchemy for this conversion process. Yes, I could do this in Java or Ruby or C or Lua, but we are using Python and SQLAlchemy, so these are questions about Python and SQLAlchemy. If I was doing this in Java then I might be posting a question about models in Hibernate, but this company uses Python and SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Bruno, I think you misunderstood the question. I wasn't asking about what mapping I should use, I was asking how to avoid collisions when I have to use models that have the same name, but are completely different. van's answer seems reasonable to me.

Comment: AOK sorry, I indeed misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the models are defined in different packages(or modules or even libraries), just use import with aliases in order to handle the same model names:

```
# file: migration.py

from myoldcrm.models import User as UserOLD
from myoldcrm import Session as SessionOLD

from mynewcrm.models import User
from mynewcrm import Session

def migrate_users():
    users = SessionOLD.query(UserOLD).all()
    for user in users:
        ser = user.serialize() # or any other way you have to do this
        des = User.deserialize(ser) # deserialize using new model class
        Session.add(des)
    Session.commit()
```